# RedHat cluster with rgmanager or pacemaker as resource manager on Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: centos, rhel, cluster, pacemaker

I'm learning RedHat cluster and I have setup a 3 node cluster (Centos 6.7), corosync, cman and rgmanager on Oracle VirtualBox version 5.x.

The cluster is working fine (the clustat commmand shows that the service is started on node-x; selinux is off and iptables is set to allow all mode for testing purposes).

I'm stuck at setting up fencing and I'm not sure if it possible to setup fencing (stonith) on VirtualBox or VMware Workstation as according to some documentation I'm referring to, it requires special hardware  like "HP iLO management board, IPMI management board, some special network switch".

Please suggest me some alternatives or workarounds.

Comment: http://bigthinkingapplied.com/creating-a-ha-cluster-with-red-hat-cluster-suite-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

The best rgmanager cluster tutorial I've seen is this:
[AN!Cluster Tutorial 2](https://alteeve.ca/w/AN!Cluster_Tutorial_2)

Fencing is the act of one cluster node making sure a failed node can't access the shared resources. The STONITH (Shoot The Other Node In The Head) also called power fencing, basically reboots the failed node.

It does that either using a remote console (like HP iLO, Dell DRAC, etc.) or by instructing the hypervisor to reset the VM (in the case of virtual machines).
You need to find the correct fencing agent for VirtualBox.

In case there is no VirtualBox fencing agent, you'll have to use VMware/KVM/Xen to host them - they do have the needed agents.